# Form button submit value don't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I got the following form but it dont work.I read plenty of examples but cant understand what I do wrong..
Can someone explain me please why $_POST["choice"] don't work?
I can post whole code if nessesary but I though it dont need..

```
<form action="2.php" method="POST">
  <div class="question">
        <?=$question?>
    <div class="inline">
    <div class="choice1">
       <button type="submit" name="choice" class="choice" id="1" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" onclick="myFunction()" ><?=$ans_array[0]?></button>
    </div>
    <div class="choice2">
         <button type="submit" class="choice" id="2" name="choice"  onclick="myFunction()" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"><?=$ans_array[1]?></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
    <div class="choice1">
        <button type="submit" class="choice" id="3" name="choice" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"><?=$ans_array[2]?></button>
    </div>
    <div class="choice2">
        <button type="submit" class="choice" id="4" name="choice" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"><?=$ans_array[3]?></button>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

and then i got the next file 2.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["choice"];
$a = $_POST["choice"];
?>
```

but I get the following
Notice: Undefined index: choice in  on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: choice in  on line 3

Comment: What does your javascript function do?

Comment: Can you show us what you are receiving in the `2.php`? `var_dump($_POST)`. Also, show us your javascript `myFunction` for the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers it seemed the problem was on the following javascript as it was blocking the submit from the other buttons.Problem is solved now

```
<script>
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds

    $("<p>Delay...</p>").appendTo("body");
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You show the post as a `button` type.  Button type do not exist unless someone pushes the button.  If you are doing a submit earlier or allowing `ENTER` to cause a submit then that is undefined.

You can test this by putting this right in front of choice1

```
 <input type=hidden name=choice value='no button pushed'>
```

And if you see that, then that's what happened

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem as the form only has 4 submit buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I test it and indeed it seems i blocked the submit buttons with javascipt as i had the following code                                            `    <script>
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
    form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds
    
    $("<p>Delay...</p>").appendTo("body");
    });
   </script>`